# Variance of $\frac{t}{T}X+Y$

Tags: variance, finance

I would like to understand how the variance of multiple random variables is computed when weights of the variables change over time. For example, let $\displaystyle X_{t}$ be a random variable at time $\displaystyle t$ and $\displaystyle Y_{t}$ be a random variable at time $\displaystyle t$. At time  $\displaystyle 0\leq t\leq T$, given $\displaystyle X_{t}$ and $\displaystyle Y_{t}$, we have

\begin{equation}
Z_{t}=\frac{t}{T}X_{t}+Y_{t}
\end{equation}

I would like to understand if is there any sense to compute

\begin{equation}
\text{var}(Z_{t})=\text{var}(\frac{t}{T}X_{t}+Y_{t})\\
\text{var}(Z_{t})=\text{var}(\frac{t}{T}X_{t}) + \text{var}(Y_{t}) + 2 \text{cov}(\frac{t}{T}X_{t}, Y_{t})\\
\end{equation}

I am asking this because the value of some financial derivatives with specific maturity can depend on their current price and forward price in a way that the weight of the current price increases towards maturity. That is, the random variables are dependent. This is just a simplified formulation of such a problem.

Additionally, if we assume the random variables to be normally distributed, how wrong would it be to assume the first term to be $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}X_{t}$ since the average of $\displaystyle \frac{t}{T}$ within $\displaystyle [0, T]$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you just get different results for different values of t.  There is no need to assume normal distributions.  The same result would hold for any random variables that have finite means and variances. Finishing what you wrote would give you

$$\operatorname{Var}(Z_t) = \left(\frac{t}{T}\right)^2 \operatorname{Var}(X_t)+ \operatorname{Var}(Y_t) + 2 \left(\frac{t}{T}\right) \operatorname{Cov}(X_t ,Y_t) .$$

This is simply defined for each $t$ between $0$ and $T.$ There is no reason to average over the values of $t.$

Comment: You forgot to divide by T. The sum is (T+1)/2, but the mean is (T+1)/(2T). And that holds if you start summing from 1. But here we start from 0, so then indeed we get (T+1)/(2(T+1))=1/2.

Comment: The sum of the values for t is T(T+1)/2 its average is T/2 since there are T+1 terms. So the average for t/T is 1/2 as you suggest. So the OP is correct. Still doing that averaging makes no sense to me. I am editing my answer.